# I accidently shorted a circuit on my motherboard

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure

I was working on installing a new motherboard. I accidentally shorted a circuit on the board with my screwdriver. I saw a few tiny sparks when it touched. Now the board wont power on at all. Is there anything I can do or is my board toast?

Comment: Why would you even “work on installing a new motherboard” while it is powered on?

Comment: Youthful exuberance? Benchtesting?

Comment: The motherboard wasnt powered on. The power supply was plugged in and turned on though the computer itself was not turned on. Inexperience on my part.

Comment: Just because the fans aren’t running doesn’t mean there’s nothing active. There’s plenty of active components on a “turned-off” motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell from what you described what damage might have been done.  A technician would have to examine the board and run tests.  However, unless you got lucky and the damage was something obvious, it could cost more to diagnose the problem than a new board (and there is no guarantee that the technician could fix the damage).

If you contact the manufacturer, they might be able to put you in touch with whoever repairs their defective boards.  They might have a deal where you send them your board and they exchange it for another rebuilt board for a fixed price.  Expect the exchange cost to be at least half the price of a new board and carry a warranty of 30 to 90 days.

Before you replace it, test the power supply.  It is possible that the motherboard is OK and it was the power supply that was damaged.  When you power it on, do you see any signs of electrical activity (indicator lights, fans, etc.)?  Even if the motherboard is damaged, you should see initial signs of electrical activity if the power supply is OK.  The pin diagram for the power supply may be on or inside the power supply box and you can check it with a voltmeter.  Failures are generally absence of a voltage, not inaccurate voltage, so don't worry if the voltages are inaccurate if the cables are disconnected. If you read anywhere in the ballpark of what the voltages are supposed to be, it is likely OK.

Comment: Thanks. The power supply wasnt the issue. After I gave up on the new board, I put the old one back in and everything worked like it used to.

Answer (score 0):

While installing a motherboard, was the power connected and turned/powered on?
If so, you can give a last try: turn off the motherboard, disconnect the powersupply and wait for 5 to 10 minutes. Then connect the power supply, power on and try turning on.
If that doesn't work, the chances are the motherboard needs a replacement.

Kindly note that, power supply must be disconnected (if not, at least turned off) before installing the motherboard as issues like this tend to occur.

Comment: Yes it was. I put the old board back in and put the new (possibly fried) one back in the box. I'll give it a try in the morning. Fingers crossed.