# Burning Smell Coming From Laptop's Motherboard - Short Circuit?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, hardware-failure

I have this laptop for about three years now, and I thought I should clean out the dust it has accumulated over the years, so I did but when I was closing up the laptop something bad happened.

My laptop has two back plates, I put the main back plate into it's place as you can see in this picture:

[image: Back Plate]

And began screwing the screws, but one screw slipped inside on the motherboard through one of the holes, and a strange burning smell started coming from the motherboard, I started wiggling around the laptop to see if I can get the screw out without removing the back plate, so the screw could have possible sit anywhere in that area shown on the following picture. I unscrewed the screws that I just had screwed and found the screw that slipped sitting on the motherboard as shown in the following picture:

[image: Burn Smell]

I removed the screw and saw no visual or physical damage. The laptop was not turned on during this, but the battery was attached to the motherboard of course. I can remember it was not plugged in to the wall outlet though.

I tested the laptop, it works fine, I played some games for some minutes on it as well, but it just worries me so much, did I burn some capacitors or did I damage the laptop somehow? Is it going to die on me any soon?

---

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/common-mistakes-damage-ruin-motherboard/

[I accidently shorted a circuit on my motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/808613/i-accidently-shorted-a-circuit-on-my-motherboard)

Comment: Did you do this with the laptop turned ON?!

Comment: The laptop was not turned on during this, but the battery was attached to the motherboard of course. I can remember it was not plugged in to the wall outlet though. Added this to the question as well.

Comment: A guess: you damaged a resistor, some part is now getting too much power and heats up too much. There's really no easy way to tell without a multimeter. Never open up a laptop with the battery inside, even if it's off and unplugged from the wall. (Talking about the main battery, not the BIOS battery.)

Comment: @confetti Thanks for the comment. If that would be the case, I don't think I can just buy a resistor and replace it right? The whole motherboard has to be changed? And since you mentioned I shouldn't have opened it with the batter inside, the whole idea of cleaning the laptop was bad I guess...

Comment: IF you can track down which exact resistor you broke then sure. Given the ability to work a soldering iron (not beginner friendly especially with SMD parts), it's possible **if** the overheating part has not been permanently damaged. Your best bet would be to take it to a specialist. It's a good idea to clean the insides of a PC/Laptop at least once or twice a year, but always with precautions.

Comment: If everything is now working, there is no more smell, and there is no visible sign of damage, you might not have done any permanent damage.  Or, it might have shortened the service life of some part.  There isn't really a practical way to determine that.  Just use the laptop.  If it fails at a younger age than you would expect, you'll potentially know why.  At that point, your record of where the screw was might help to locate a failed part that can be repaired.